# codelite autocompletion not (really) working

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codelite

I am currently migrating to CodeLite, as a former Code::Blocks user. Overall, i think CodeLite is a pleasure to use. CB had its flaws, but most of the stuff was working. That includes autocompletion/code completion, for some reason, that just doesn't want to work with CodeLite.
Here are a few of the problems i have with codelite:

[image: Mutex no autocompletion]

Here `m_KernelStateMutex` is an instance of the class `std::mutex`, but whenever i place the dot, i don't get any sort of completion or list of available members. Same goes for namespaces, where auto completion sort of works:

[image: namespace autocompletion error]

As you can see, none of the the `std::chrono` members are visible/shown. The error is the same for just the `std` namespace. And then finally, i have an error with header autocompletion: i added the `include` folder in my projects root to the include paths, it compiles - but autocompletions shows some sort of BS:

[image: header autocompletion error]

What could be the cause of these problems?
My platform is Windows 10 64bit, CodeLite version 9.1.4

## Update

Just installed an ancient CodeLite version (6.1.1), and here, everything is working fine.

[image]

Comment: The include paths completion is not a bug, its just how CodeLite found these file (relative to one of the search paths). Just keep on typing and hit Ctrl-SPACE (e.g. `cysslib/`)

Comment: @Eran see the issue #1204 on github please. code completion just suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize this issue:
It is a bug in CodeLite which was fixed in this intermediate release: 
http://codelite.org/downloads/codelite/weekly/wip/codelite-amd64-9.15.exe

See the discussion here:
https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/1204

**NOTE**
If the link for CodeLite 9.1.5 above is broken, it means that you can download a normal installer from our website and this intermediate release is not needed anymore